# Let's encrypt, blazor and Azure Linux Web App

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, blazor

I'm trying to add certificate with let's encrytp to my Blazor Server App that is hosted in a linux azure web app.

My issue is, that the path `/.well-known/acme-challenge` redirect to my Index page so when I try to create my certificate, I have an error.

Do you know how to achieve this with blazor ?

**EDIT :**

After following the link from @Yan, the folder still not accessible ( in dev & production)

Here the configuration :

```
 public static class AcmeChallengeResponderExtensions
{
    private const string WellKnownFolder = @".well-known";
    private const string WellKnownRequestPath = @"/.well-known";
    private const string AcmeChallenceFolder = @"acme-challenge";


    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAcmeChallengeResponder(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var rootFolderPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var root = new DirectoryInfo(rootFolderPath);
        if (!root.Exists)
            throw new ArgumentException("The provided folder does not exist");

        var wellKnownFolder = root.CreateSubdirectory(WellKnownFolder);
        var acmeChallenge = root.CreateSubdirectory(Path.Combine(WellKnownFolder, AcmeChallenceFolder));

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            RequestPath = new PathString(WellKnownRequestPath),
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(rootFolderPath, WellKnownFolder)),
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        });

        return app;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this blog post .. not sure why it's there any more but here is the google cached version  https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jyo1NXBUo4EJ:https://www.azurehead.com/lets-encrypt-challenge-blazor/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari

Comment: Yes I saw it, but not able to open it... I don't know the existence of webcache, amazing thanks, I will take a look :)